# Publish VS dot net core application without exe

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, publish

I have an asp.net mvc dot net core 3.1 application
I want to publish it for deploy
However on publishing it also gives an application exe which is not allowed in shared hosting
Can someone guide me how to publish without exe

Comment: "it also gives an application exe which is not allowed in shared hosting" - If your webhost actually has imposed a system that blocks you from FTPing files with `.exe` extensions then **get a better web-host** that actually knows what they're doing.

Comment: While you can run ASP.NET Core 1.0 and 2.0 (but not 3.0+) applications under IIS's .NET Framework pipeline (i.e. ASP.NET Core-on-.NET Framework), this does not apply to ASP.NET Core 3.0+ applications. (As far as I know) **the `.exe` is required** because that's how IIS' reverse-proxy starts and runs your .NET Core code out-of-proc.